# Align h1 text with surrounding borders (supported by gmail)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get lines to surround an h1 but I'm having problems aligning the text with the surrounding lines. I've used embedded before / after attributes but I couldn't get them to work in Gmail so I opted of an inline attribute using borders on the h1. Currently the text "January 2018" is aligning below the surrounding lines. See code below.

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffe800; 
    font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 22px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


<h1 style="border-left: 150px solid #ffffff; border-right: 150px solid #ffffff; height: 3px;   display: block;">January 2018</h1>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe increase the height of the `h1` box, or change the `text-align`? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using vertical-align: top but that did nothing. I've played with the font size too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your display property from `display:block` to `display:inline`

Comment: I changed the display property to inline and it aligned the text but it also increased the height of the borders to match the text size. So halfway there?

Comment: hmm.  I think it's from the padding on h1.  I put in a code pen [link](https://codepen.io/dpalmquist84/pen/VyMMjY).  I tried to wrap it all in a div hoping it work